# Android handler does not start

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I have app where i generate longitude and latitude from address i use `AsyncTask` where i start in `doInBackground` generating coordinates my problem is that in my code it appears that `Handler` is not turned on when i put this line :

```
viedotGeoCoo();
```

outside from `AsyncTask` it appears that everything is working perfectly.

This is my code:

```
public class AddEvent extends Activity {
    Button addressButton, timeButton;
    TextView addressTV,textView2;
    TextView latLongTV, longCo, textView4;
    EditText editNosaukums;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_event);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        addressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
        latLongTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latLongTV);
        longCo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longCo);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        editNosaukums = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNosaukums);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        addressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
        addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.addressButton:
                        DownloadFilesTask task = new DownloadFilesTask();
                        task.execute((Void[]) null);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Looper.prepare();
            viedotGeoCoo();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             Log.e("Add_Event", "GEO IZDEVAAS");
             sutitDatus();

        }
    }



    public void viedotGeoCoo() {

        EditText editValsts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editValsts);
        EditText editPilseta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPilseta);
        EditText editIelaNr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIelaNr);

        String valsts = editValsts.getText().toString();
        String pilseta = editPilseta.getText().toString();
        String ielanr = editIelaNr.getText().toString();


        String address = valsts + " "+ pilseta + " " + ielanr;

        Log.e("ADD_EVENT", "HANDLER SAAKAS");


        GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
        locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());//jadublice jaataisa speciala klase


        GeocodingLocationLat locationAddressLat = new GeocodingLocationLat();
        locationAddressLat.getAddressFromLocation(address,
        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandlerLat());//jadublice jaataisa speciala klase

        Log.e("ADD_EVENT", "GEO GENEREETS");

    }



    //sanjem stringu no com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.GeocodingLocation.java
    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            Log.e("Add_Event", "HANDLER_LONG");

        }
    }

    private class GeocoderHandlerLat extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            Log.e("Add_Event", "Handler_Lat");

        }

    }


}
```

Has anyone have any idea why my code is not working properly?

Comment: Just move all the code that inflates views and retrieves their text values to UI thread and pass "address" as a parameter to the AsyncTask - this will make your code a lot more readable and will solve your problems.

Comment: @Egor no that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calling videotGeoConn() in background Thread but Thread is exiting after doInBackground
You can call a constructor from super class and pass main looper:

```
private class GeocoderHandlerLat extends Handler {
        public GeocoderHandlerLat(){
              super(Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            Log.e("Add_Event", "Handler_Lat");

        }

    }
```

Or you can add a paremeter to videotGeoConn and create handler in onPreExecuteMethod:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private GeocoderHandlerLatHandler handler;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
            handler = new GeocoderHandlerLat();
    }    
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
               // Looper.prepare() is not needed
               viedotGeoCoo(handler);

            return null;
        }
}
```